# Algorithm for fitting abstract distances in 2D

Tags: algorithm, geometry, visualization, computational-geometry, data-visualization

Suppose we are given a small number of objects and "distances" between them -- what algorithm exists for fitting these objects to points in two-dimensional space in a way that approximates these distances?

The difficulty here is that the "distance" is not distance in Euclidean space -- this is why we can only fit/approximate.

(for those interested in what the notion of distance is precisely, it is the symmetric distance metric on the power set of a (finite) set).

Comment: Do you have a distance for every possible pair of points?

Comment: Is there a function that would allow you to more closely map your current distance onto representative Euclidean distance.  Solutions that treat the difference as a simple error won't produce a good result if this the case.  If your non-Euclidean distances better map to your representation of them in Euclidean space after applying some other function, it makes sense to apply this prior to attempting to plot your values.

Comment: Imagine you have n points, and the distance between any pair of points is one. This is clearly a metric. You need a n-1 dimensional space to embed the points isometrically. How  would you like this case to be mapped into the 2 dimensional plane ?

Comment: @glowcoder: yes, I have a distance for each pair.  Shane MacLaughlin : since the number of points N is small, I could map them accurately into (N-1)-dimensional space.  This would give be the difficult situation of Alexandre C. -- are there algorithms that cope well with this?

Comment: I believe there are algorithms to project points of dimension n to dimension n-1. So you could solve your system in the n-1 dimension perfectly, perform some calculation to determine the 'fullest' angle at which to project your image into n-2 space, and repeat this process until you're in 2d space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the number of objects is small, you can create an undirected weighted graph, where these objects would be nodes and the edge between any two nodes has the weight that corresponds to the distance between these two objects. You end up with n*(n-1)/2 edges.

Once the graph is created, there are a lot of visualization software and algorithms that correspond to graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Try a triangulation method, something like this;

- Start by taking three objects with known distances between them, and create a triangle in an arbitrary grid based on the side lengths.
- For each additional object that has not been placed, find at least three other objects that have been placed that you have known distances to, and use those distances to place the object using distance / distance intersection (i.e. the intersection point of the three circles centred around the fixed points with radii of the distances)
- Repeat until all objects have been placed, or no more objects can be placed.

For unplaced objects, you could start another similar exercise, and then use any available distances to relate the separate clusters.  Look up triangulation and trilateration networks for more info.

**Edit:** As per the comment below, where the distances are approximate and include an element of error, the above approach may be used to establish provisional coordinates for each object, and those coordinates may then be adjusted using a least squares method such as [variation of coordinates](http://www.lpi.nsw.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/71273/HAVOC.pdf)  This would also cater for weighting distances based on their magnitude as required.  For a more detailed description, check [Ghilani & Wolf's book on the subject](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471697281).  This depends very much on the nature of the differences between your distances and how you would like your objects represented in Euclidean space based on those distances.  The relationship needs to be modelled and applied as part of any solution.

Comment: What if there are four objects with known distance to a given object, and the distances are not consistent?

Comment: @ElKamina, if this is the case use the above procedure to produce provisional coordinates, and then carry out a least square adjustment, such as variation of coordinates to perform a best fit.

Comment: Interesting!  But I'm not sure I understand what to do if the fourth object to be placed is close to all three of the objects already placed, which are themselves very far apart.  In such a case their circles will not intersect.

Comment: It depends on how many distances you have between each object.  For the above to work you really need each object to have a minimum of three distances to any other object.  If you have only two distances from any given object, it can reasonably lie on either side of the line joining the two objects to which there are distances.  If there is only one distance, it can lie anywhere on the circle defined by that distance.  If there are no distances to a given object you can place it anywhere on the plane.  Cont...

Comment: ... If the fourth object does not have three distances to any objects already placed on the plane, you need to skip over it and try with other objects, until you can either place an object or run out of objects to place.  You repeat this procedure until you can't place any more objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of [Multidimensional Scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling), or more generally, [Nonlinear dimensionality reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction).  There are a fair amount of tools/libraries for doing this available (see the second link for a list).