# Any algorithm to reconstruct 2d mesh from distances between points

Tags: geometry, 2d

There is an input array of distances between points. Is there any algorithm to reconstruct 2d mesh from this array?

Comment: Please give us an example of your input. The question in its current state is a bit underspecified.

Comment: @Yuri: For example we have array a[][], where a[i][j] is distance between i and j points: a[0][1]=4, a[0][2]=5, a[0][3]=10, a[1][2]=3, a[1][3]=sqrt(68), a[2][3]=sqrt(29)       let's think that for point 1 X=0, then there will be points coordinates (0,0) (0,4) (3,4) (8,6) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can triangulate the points with a delaunay triangulation. Its also consider a good triangulation because there isn't any other point in the circumference of a triangle except the 3 points of the triangle on the circumference. You can also try a dimension reduction. For example translate the points to a binary and interleave it. Treat it as base-10 number then pick the distances and reverse the process (to get the co-ordinate). Then triangulate it.

Comment: I think the issue is not the construction of a set of points to a mesh, but rather a set of distances between points and a mesh. So, in steps: Set of distances -> Set of coordinates -> Then your Delaunay triangulation or any other mesh reconstruction

Comment: I have no coordinates of points, just array of distances between each 2 points. And I want to convert them into mesh

Comment: @Yuri:From distances to point is trivial for example when it satisfy the triangle inequality?

Comment: @Phpdna I wouldn't call that trivial. Mind writing down a few lines of pseudo code in your answer?

Comment: @Yuri:After rethink it you are right but question is very unspecific. What you can do ia place the points randomly on each axis with the distances in the array.

Comment: @Phpdna: Let's think that points are evenly distributed on a plane and we know all distances between them (not a case when all points are in line)

Comment: @Ferluht:IMO my answers is helpful? Consider to accept it or upvote!?

Comment: @phpdna, sorry, your answer is not helpful in the current state. You need to provide more details. "Placing it randomly on the axes" is not going to work either. At least, not that simple. Try it :-)

Comment: @Yuri:And remove backups? Helpful?

Comment: @phpdna no. Try to write the code for yourself, and see. You cannot "just place them using the distances", that is the entire question. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9180349/639109, you will end up with a set of linear equations which you will need to solve

Comment: @Yuri:The linked question is not about euklidian distance.  IMO read my comment.

Comment: @phpdna The distance function is actually the _least_ important part in the story. In all honesty, your answer doesn't contribute anything to the question. And why do you refuse to provide pseudo code? Maybe because it isn't as simple as you keep portraying it is?

Comment: @Yuri:You doesn't seems to make any sense.

Comment: @Yuri:There is also dimensional reduction. I can map 1d to a 2d. It works with any dimensions.